# Remove Row from MySQL after [VARIABLE] days

Tags: php, mysql

Trying to create a PHP function to delete rows from a DB after a variable number of days. Each row has a `days_to_advertise` column and a `date_created` column.

So far, I've tried just running below query :

```
`$check_and_remove = "DELETE FROM perch2_xreceiver_listings 
                      WHERE date_created < UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL days_to_advertise DAY));";`
```

I'm not convinced that this will work - do I need to use a `foreach` in some way?

Thanks

Comment: Executing a `DELETE FROM` query does not require iteration. It will delete all rows that match the `WHERE` clause

Comment: Just turn your query into a select and you will see which records it picks up. If those records are the ones you expect to delete, then your query will work fine. If not, then you need to adjust it.